# Why is the reference to .NET runtime lost with this dockerfile?

Tags: .net, docker

I have a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Project/Project.csproj", "Project/"]
COPY ["Reference/Reference.csproj", "Reference/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Project/Project.csproj"
RUN dotnet restore "Reference/Reference.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Project"
RUN dotnet build "Project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project.dll"]
```

but when i want to build and run it with `docker build -f Dockerfile -t mytag . && docker run --name myproject mytag`  i get an error after the build:

```
You must install or update .NET to run this application.
2022-11-09T15:48:22.642099385Z 
2022-11-09T15:48:22.642104961Z App: /app/Project.dll
2022-11-09T15:48:22.642108153Z Architecture: x64
2022-11-09T15:48:22.642111392Z Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '6.0.0' (x64)
2022-11-09T15:48:22.642115860Z .NET location: /usr/share/dotnet/
2022-11-09T15:48:22.642119020Z 
2022-11-09T15:48:22.642122144Z No frameworks were found.
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `runtime` image is meant for console apps. Yours is an ASP.NET app, so you should use the `aspnet` runtime image instead.
Replace

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base
```

with

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
```